# Heroku deployment issue with deleted table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to deploy to Heroku for the first time. During database migration I get error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "new_shops" does not exist

: DROP TABLE "new_shops"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-new4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:
in `async_exec'
```

new_shops is a table I thought I deleted with everything related to it (I followed instructions I've found here, although don't remember exactly what I did), but obviously I didn't.
Table itself is dropped, but something else is there. I am a newbie, so I have no idea what to do now or where to look.

What is the best way to destroy everything related to this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table probably doesn't exist. You can check by running:

```
heroku pg:psql
\d new_shops
```

If it doesn't exist you should comment or remove the migration that is trying to drop the table.